# Optimal way to create mdadm raid 1 on USB adapter and then put it into slot on motherboard

Tags: linux, debian, raid, mdadm

I'm looking for the optimal way how to perform the task.

On one of my debian servers:

1. I have 2xSSD connected via USB adapter (no free ports on motherboard)
2. I need to create RAID 1 MDADM array (2USB disks) and copy data from existing HDDs
3. Existing HDDs (not system part) will be replaced by the new 2xSSD array

I have no problem with creating MDADM arrays on USB. **The question is rather will the array still work after moving those disks from USB do actual motherboard slots** and how `/etc/mdadm.conf` shall be populated in this case. For sure identifiers `sdg`,`sdi` will change.

A glimpse of my current mdamd.conf

```
# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=4639c0f2:e1070742:73fa5cdf:2cd5a5cb name=debian:0

# This configuration was auto-generated on Wed, 27 Dec 2017 20:35:27 +0100 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=debian:1 UUID=224292b7:3d065ef2:1e2178cc:3006f7c9
```

And sample mdadm config (here I see drive indentifiers by drive letters)

```
md1 : active raid1 sdc2[0] sdd2[2]
      1465291776 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/11 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[2]
      249925632 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/2 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mdadm builds its configurations under the hood using device UUIDs, so even if you move these drives from being connected via USB to being connected directly to the motherboard via SATA, the array should still be constructed properly.

Comment: Thanks, I've already followed my approach a few days ago and it worked as expected.